# Fit div with img to page height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple container with images that looks like a table, so HTML and CSS would look like :

```css
.cabinet {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.module {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: black;
}

.module > button > img {
    width: 100%;
}

.cabinet-info-button {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabinet">
    <div>
        <div class="module">
            <button class="cabinet-info-button">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500577329392-f0af6d7dd827?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGlnaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" />
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="module">
            <button class="cabinet-info-button">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500577329392-f0af6d7dd827?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGlnaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="module">
            <button class="cabinet-info-button">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500577329392-f0af6d7dd827?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGlnaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" />
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="module">
            <button class="cabinet-info-button">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500577329392-f0af6d7dd827?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGlnaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80)" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="module">
            <button class="cabinet-info-button">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500577329392-f0af6d7dd827?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGlnaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" />
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="module">
            <button class="cabinet-info-button">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500577329392-f0af6d7dd827?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGlnaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like this to *auto-fit my browser's height*, I managed to manipulate the width of the element, but it's not exactly what I expected.
In fact, if I flip the screen that is higher than it's width, it will (for example) fit to 25% width, leaving lots of empty space beneath.

I tried setting the height at 100vh or 100%, but it gives me nothing, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put inside the image tag `object-fit:cover` so whenever the height of the div is adjusted the image will also cover the whole div width and height. Alternatively, though this might take time by using `child elements` of your class `module` you can alternately set each images to backgrounds of each `module` class.

Like this:

```
.module {
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: ; // set your own width
    height: ; // set your own height
}

.module:first-child {
    background-image:url(images/image1.png);
}

.module:nth-child(2) {
    background-image:url(images/image2.png);
}

.module:nth-child(3) {
    background-image:url(images/image3.png);
}

.module:nth-child(4) {
    background-image:url(images/image4.png);
}
```

Comment: And what if children are dynamic, for example 100